# VirtualBox can't access any files it didn't make itself

Tags: macos, permission, virtualbox

So I moved over to a new Mac mini and now VirtualBox can not load any files that it didn't make itself.  I was attempting to load a VDI created on my previous Mac mini into a new install of VirtualBox.

As a test to make sure the files were okay, I tried running as su.  Which allowed it to use the VDI files.

Another example is that I have an ISO in ~/Downloads.  I downloaded it from MSDN on this Mac mini and I can open it in Finder.  Meanwhile VirtualBox (which I believe is running as me) throws an error saying access denied when I try to mount it.

If I create a new VDI/VHD/etc using VirtualBox in ~/Downloads it can access the file without issue.  It just can not use any of my existing files.

I've been trying to fix this for a few days now.  It's probably going to be something silly.  This is on MacOS Catalina 10.15.6.

Although I've used ~/Downloads as an example, it happens with any folder.
Note that I've moved my user folder to an external drive using advanced options in Users/Groups.  I don't think that should matter but it's worth mentioning just in case.

I forgot to mention that I have checked the file permissions and, in an attempt to fix, have made things way too open.  Here is the output of ls -l on the location of the existing VDI and the downloaded ISO:

file path: /Volumes/Macintosh USB HD12/Vamo's Files/Sony/PS2/PS2.vdi

```
vamo@Vamos-Mac-mini Sony % ls -loe@
total 8
drwxrwxrwx@  7 vamo  224  6 Apr  2019 PS1
    com.apple.serverdocs.markup 117 
 0: user:vamo allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
drwxrwxrwx@  7 vamo  224 14 Sep 20:13 PS2
    com.apple.serverdocs.markup 117 
 0: user:vamo allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
drwxrwxrwx+  4 vamo  128 14 Jul  2017 PS3
 0: user:vamo allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
drwxrwxrwx@  6 vamo  192 27 Apr  2017 PSP
    com.apple.serverdocs.markup 117 
 0: user:vamo allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
-rw-rw-rw-+  1 vamo  859 16 Dec  2018 Readme.lnk
 0: user:vamo allow read,write,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
drwxrwxrwx@ 13 vamo  416  2 Aug  2017 Vita
    com.apple.serverdocs.markup 117 
 0: user:vamo allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
```

```
vamo@Vamos-Mac-mini PS2 % ls -loe@
total 537952480
-rw-rw-rw-@ 1 vamo      13742080 20 May 12:58 TestHB.iso
    Zone.Identifier          231 
 0: user:vamo allow read,write,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 vamo  275417923584 14 Sep 14:39 PS2.vdi
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS             16 
 0: user:vamo allow read,write,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
drwxrwxrwx@ 7 vamo           224 29 Dec  2017 Tools
    com.apple.serverdocs.markup          117 
 0: user:vamo allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
-rw-rw-rw-+ 1 vamo          1550 20 Apr  2017 ps2 - Shortcut.lnk
 0: user:vamo allow read,write,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
```

file path: ~/Downloads/en_windows_server_2019_updated_aug_2020_x64_dvd_f4bab427.iso
which is actually:
/Volumes/Macintosh USB HD0/vamo/Downloads/en_windows_server_2019_updated_aug_2020_x64_dvd_f4bab427.iso

```
vamo@Vamos-Mac-mini Downloads % ls -loe@
total 10661856
drwxrwxrwx@ 3 vamo          96 11 Feb  2016 BatChmod.app
    com.apple.quarantine            57 
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 vamo     4847038 15 Sep 08:15 LaunchControl-1.50.1.tar.bz2
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS           16 
    com.apple.macl          72 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDownloadedDate            53 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms           156 
    com.apple.quarantine            57 
drwxrwxrwx@ 3 vamo          96  5 Jun 10:42 LaunchControl.app
    com.apple.quarantine            57 
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 vamo      608349 14 Sep 13:27 SymbolicLinker2.1.1.dmg
    com.apple.diskimages.fsck           20 
    com.apple.diskimages.recentcksum            80 
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS           16 
    com.apple.macl          72 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDownloadedDate            53 
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms           644 
    com.apple.quarantine            57 
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 vamo  5438150656 14 Sep 10:28 en_windows_server_2019_updated_aug_2020_x64_dvd_f4bab427.iso
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS           16 
    com.apple.macl          72
```

This is what VirtualBox says when I try to mount the VDI:
Permission problem accessing the file for the medium '/Volumes/Macintosh USB HD12/Vamo's Files/Sony/PS2/PS2.vdi' (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED).

and the ISO:
Permission problem accessing the file for the medium '/Volumes/Macintosh USB HD0/vamo/Downloads/en_windows_server_2019_updated_aug_2020_x64_dvd_f4bab427.iso' (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED).

Comment: I have a 2018 Mac mini. I do not have problems reading ISO files copied from other Macs. I am not running as a su (root user). I am not sure why you think this is necessary. I am using Mojave. Did you do a clean install of the current version of VirtualBox or did you migrate VirtualBox when you moved to the new Mac mini? Can you document where the ISO file came from?

Comment: Again the ISO file is just an example as that's what I was going to use to install Windows Server 2019 onto a fresh VDI.  The ISO was from MSDN (or whatever it's called now).

I migrated my VDIs across and VirtualBox can not access them.  I'll edit the post to make that clearer.

VirtualBox is a new install.

Comment: Have you checked the _permissions_ on the _files_?

Comment: I have.  Good shout for me to include the output of ls -l though in the question.

Comment: Try including `ls -lOe@`. Where `O` is for file flags, `e` is for Access Control Lists (ACL) and `@` is for extended attributes.

Comment: Check the folder security.  Simplest way is in Finder - give yourself read+write and take option to ripple this down to all objects below.  No Mac handy - forgive me description is from memory!

Comment: I've swapped out the ls -l output for ls -loe@.  Thank you for explaining what each did.

Comment: Prior to posting this I had already tried giving myself permission in Finder and then using 'Apply to all enclosed items'.  Unfortunately that didn't work.